# Ready only error and const in es6 mistake

Tags: ecmascript-6, constants, strict

I'm receiving an error of read-only in this script that I'm trying to run.

I'm trying to learn const and the new es6 and I have to admit that it is pretty straightforward but in this case, I'm not 100% sure that that's the problem.

Here's my code:

```
$(() => {
    const containerImage = document.querySelector( '.images' );
    const getPictures = () => {
        $.ajax({url: "https:myurl/photos.json", success: function(result) {
            const singleImage = result.photos;
            const content = "";
            content += "<div class='row'>";
            for(let i = 0; i < singleImage.length; i++){
                content.innerHTML += `<div class="col-md-4">
                <img src=${singleImage[i].image}>
                </div>`;
            };
            content += "</div>";
            containerImage.innerHTML = content;
        }});

    }
    getPictures();
});
```

Does anyone notice any strange thing in my code?

Plus the console mention and throw this error:

```
function _readOnlyError(name) { throw new Error("\"" + name + "\" is read-only"); }
```

But I'm not even in the strict mode.

Comment: Why do you use `content.innerHTML` in a variable that is not a DOM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consts can't be modified. Change:

```
const content = ""; 
content += "<div class='row'>";
```

to

```
let content = "";
content += "<div class='row'>";
```